# Deselect from collectionView and cancel item from array

Tags: arrays, swift, uicollectionview

I have the following code:

```
 var selectedIndexPaths = [NSDate]()

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,  didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as?  PartExpense

        if cell?.selected == true {
            cell?.layer.borderWidth = 4.0
            cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor

            selectedIndexPaths.append(cell!.idPartecipant)

            print(selectedIndexPaths)


        }
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        if cell?.selected == false {
            cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor


            if let index = selectedIndexPaths.indexOf(indexPath.row) {
                selectedIndexPaths.removeAtIndex(index)
                print(selectedIndexPaths)
            }

        }

    }
```

everything goes well until line: 
    if let index = selectedIndexPaths.indexOf(indexPath.row)

This is the error: "Cannot convert value of type Int to expected type NSDate" How can I do to achieve this? How can I convert array in order to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you wrote that is asking of all the NSDates in that array what is the index of the date "indexPath.row". The error is saying indexPath.row is an int and not a date. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to put in array  this particular element idPartecipant that is an Nsdate stored with coreData. When I deselect the row I need that the element is removed.

Comment: First find the date that was deselected by searching the original data source for the data (the array used in cellForItemAtIndexPath). Once you have the one that was deselected then search you selectedIndexPaths array for that date
       
     if let deselectedData:NSDate = dataSouce[indexPath.row]   {   
       if let index = selectedIndexPaths.indexOf(deselectedData)   {    
       selectedIndexPaths.removeAtIndex(index)
    }
    }

Comment: with your code, when I deselect sometimes   I got this error: "fatal error: Index out of range"

Comment: That means your math is off somewhere. Say it was looking for the NSDate at index 2 but there were only 2 elements in the array. The first element was at index 0 and the second one at index 1. Nothing in index 2. "fatal error: Index out of range". If I helped please mark my answer correct.